# Julia: Use operator that is not in Main module

Tags: julia

What is the best way to use an operator as a function in Julia (1.x) *without defining it in the `Main` module*?
E. g. if I would like to use the `⋅` (latex: `\cdot`)  operator from the `LinearAlgebra` module without adding the operator in the `Main` module?

The naive solution gives an error:

```
julia> import LinearAlgebra
julia> LinearAlgebra.⋅(1,2)
ERROR: UndefVarError: ⋅ not defined
```

The only solution that came to my mind is:

```
import LinearAlgebra
op = LinearAlgebra.eval(Meta.parse("⋅")) # get the function object
op(1,2) # use it
```

Is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you do not want to just call

```
using LinearAlgebra
```

to bring the dot operator into current module namespace, right?

In this case, you can call operators in a module by prepending the operator with a colon:

```
import LinearAlgebra
LinearAlgebra.:⋅((1,2), (0,1))
```